# перехват ошибки SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, laravel

Не удается заблокировать ошибку после вызова функции SoapClient. Ошибка пишется в лог, даже если обернуть функцию в try catch.

вот сам лог:

```
[2019-06-26 12:18:20] local.ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://95.31.130.15:8080/work/ws/OnlineExchange.1cws?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://95.31.130.15:8080/work/ws/OnlineExchange.1cws?wsdl"
 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://95.31.130.15:8080/work/ws/OnlineExchange.1cws?wsdl' : failed to load external entity \"http://95.31.130.15:8080/work/ws/OnlineExchange.1cws?wsdl\"
 at Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\app\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C.php:39)
[stacktrace]
#0 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(137): Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException->__construct()
#1 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(123): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError()
#2 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(0): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#3 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\app\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C.php(39): SoapClient->SoapClient()
#4 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\app\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C.php(62): App\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C->getClient()
#5 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(29): App\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C->handle()
#6 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array:{Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php:29}()
#7 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#8 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#9 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#10 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->call()
#11 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Command\\Command.php(252): App\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C->execute()
#12 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(170): App\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C->run()
#13 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(865): App\\Console\\Commands\\SyncPricesWith1C->run()
#14 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(241): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#15 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(143): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#16 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(88): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#17 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#18 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\artisan(35): App\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#19 Z:\\OSPanel\\domains\\medserdcel54bp\\artisan(0): {main}()
#20 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 1):

судя по [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-soap-fault.php), можно использовать функцию is_soap_fault:

> создайте объект SoapClient с опцией exceptions, равной нулю или FALSE.

ps: с удовльствием оставил бы комментарий, но рейтинг не позволяет

Comment: пробовал не помогает. сам exception ловит но сообщение  об ошибке все равно в лог пишет, тем самым лог забивается. у меня soapclient на 2 ip работает - если первый не доступен, то будет пойман exception и вызван soapclient с другим ip. поэтому недоступность первого ip не должно логироваться.

Comment: а сам лог можно посмотреть?

Comment: т.е. лог точно по первому исключению?

Comment: добавил лог с ошибкой, если убрать exceptions = 0, он будет покороче

Comment: если это точно ошибка первого адреса, тогда не знаю :), сорри.
посмотрите trigger_error